# Green tint after upgrade to 22.04.1

Tags: graphics, desktop-environments

I have recently upgraded to 22.04.1 and since the upgrade some of the white backgrounds on applications have this green tint to them.. See attached.

I have tried xorg and wayland and both show the tint.

Graphics card is GeForce RTX 2060.

Any ideas?
[image]